# How to generate Network load on Linux machine

Tags: linux, networking, arm

I would like to know, how one can generate network load on a Linux based ARM machine which is to equivalent to video streaming over network.

Linux machine is equipeed with tool like iperf.

Comment: Yes, `iperf` is the tool to use. Set up one side as server, the other as client and set the bandwidth on the client side to the desired value (depends on what video streaming you are thinking of!). Thus, actually what is your question?

Comment: @Philippos, I was talking about any video streaming over network , Lets say Youtube vidoes.

Comment: On youtube, you'll find videos from 50 kBit/s to 4000 kBit/s. If you know how to use the tool and just want to know the parameter to set, we are the wrong department.

Comment: Ok, same can be achieved via iperf with specific set of input parameters?

Comment: Start the server with `iperf -s` and on the client with `iperfs -c your.server.name -b 1500K` for 1.5 MBit/s, for example

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently prototyping an `--isochoronous` option to the iperf client.  It would look something like:

```
--isochronous <frames per second>:<mean bandwidth>,<bandwidth variance>
```

or (pass in a pdf per frame.)

Anybody using this will want to synch the clocks of the iperf server and iperf client.

It will probably only work under Linux.  If you want to try it, let me know using the [sourceforge site discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/iperf2/discussion/general/).

Answer (score 0):

hping3 is good

```
hping3 -O 1337 -S -b -d 65495 -E /some/file --rand-source --flood <target>
```